# Geting and editing text in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to externally **get** and **set** text in a Google spreadsheet using **Java Script** from my website?

For instance, I want to set the text in the cell "A3" to say "John Smith" when a person enters their name in my website.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides speadsheet APIs for Java and .NET: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#what_can_this_api_do. You will need to use a server side language to be able use these APIs; javascript alone wouldn't serve your purpose.

**Edit:**
Of-course you may use something like [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) as well, but you'd need to put in some hooks into the spreadsheet API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Google Apps Script webapp to handle transactions for your spreadsheet. There's a very simple example in this answer: [How to post to Google Docs Form directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633154/how-to-post-to-google-docs-form-directly/18725479#18725479).

Then from Javascript, use XMLHttpRequest to interact with your API.