# Adding a row to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to pass data acquired from an ESP8266 to a Google Spreadsheet. I modified code I found here to insert data from a WiFi scan into the spreadsheet:

> [How to post to Google Docs Form directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633154/how-to-post-to-google-docs-form-directly)

My problem is that I want to enter each new network's information in a new row. I'm guessing the problem is that the case statement is too fast to add a new row for each signal. I've tried inserting a new row function after each acquired signal, but it looks like this causes the code to break out of the switch statement entirely.

> var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
>       newRange.setValues([rowData]);

I'm completely new to Javascript, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
function doGet(e) { 
Logger.log( JSON.stringify(e) );  // view parameters

var result = 'Ok'; // assume success

if (e.parameter == undefined) {
result = 'No Parameters';
}
else {
var id =//SpreadSheet ID Here
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet();
var newRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
var rowData = [];
var colData = [];
//var waktu = new Date();
rowData[0] = new Date(); // Timestamp in column A

for (var param in e.parameter) {
  Logger.log('In for loop, param='+param);
  var value = stripQuotes(e.parameter[param]);
  //Logger.log(param + ':' + e.parameter[param]);
  switch (param) {
    case 'ssid0': //Parameter
      rowData[1] = value; //Value in column B
      break;
    case 'bssid0':
      rowData[2] = value;
      break;
    case 'rssi0':
      rowData[3] = value;
  //This doesn't work
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
    newRange.setValues([rowData]);
      break;
    case 'ssid1':
      rowData[4] = value;
      break;
     case 'bssid1':
      rowData[5] = value;
      break;
     case 'rssi1':
      rowData[6] = value;
      break;       
    default:
      result = "unsupported parameter";
  }
}
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rowData));

// Write new row below
var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
newRange.setValues([rowData]);


// Return result of operation
return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}
}

function stripQuotes( value ) {
return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly isn't working? Do you get an error? Does the script just not finish? Where does this happen? Try using the debugger to find the line where the problem happens.

Comment: @ Robin, Sorry, I should have been more clear. If I use the above code, I don't get any error messages. It seems this section in the switch statement is skipped over entirely: `var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow,1,1 rowData.length)` `newRange.setValues([rowData])`The script runs, but all of the information I pass is written in the same row.